# Como fazer consulta em tabelas ManyToMany?

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, jpql

Tenho duas tabelas/entidades na base de dados com os seguintes atributos:

Carro (codigo, placa, cor)
Acessorio (codigo, descricao).

```
public Carro buscarCarroComAcessorio(Long codigo) {
    return (Carro) em.createQuery("select c from Carro c JOIN c.acessorios here c.codigo=?").setParameter(1, codigo).getSingleResult();
}
```

Estou usando a cláusula acima para retornar os acessórios, mas minha *stacktrace* me diz que além da cláusula estar em HQL está obsoleta e  que devo escreve-la em JPQL.

#### Estrutura das classes/entidades

Carro:

```
package com.jpa.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

@Entity
public class Carro implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;
    private String placa;
    private String cor;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "carro_acessorio",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_carro"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_acessorio"))
    private List<Acessorio> acessorios;

    //getters and setters
    public Long getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getPlaca() {
        return placa;
    }

    public void setPlaca(String placa) {
        this.placa = placa;
    }

    public String getCor() {
        return cor;
    }

    public void setCor(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }

    public List<Acessorio> getAcessorios() {
        return acessorios;
    }

    public void setAcessorios(List<Acessorio> acessorios) {
        this.acessorios = acessorios;
    }

    ///hashcode
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Carro other = (Carro) obj;
        if (codigo == null) {
            if (other.codigo != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

Acessório:

```
package com.jpa.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Acessorio implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;
    private String descricao;

    //getters and setters
    public Long getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    ///hashing
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Acessorio other = (Acessorio) obj;
        if (codigo == null) {
            if (other.codigo != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Qual é a stacktrace completa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A consulta parece estar incorreta, se deseja retornar os acessórios também, em uma única consulta JPQL. Neste caso, você precisa usar o `FETCH`. A princípio, eu escreveria a consulta desta maneira:

```
SELECT car FROM Carro as car JOIN FETCH car.acessorios WHERE car.codigo=?
```

Assim, você retorna a entidade carro (`SELECT car FROM Carro as car`) com os acessórios de cada carro (`JOIN FETCH car.acessorios`) dos carros com código igual ao código do parâmetro (`WHERE car.codigo=?`)